# Force DOM refresh in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am running a loop within a click event handler doing the following:

- run heavy computation (takes 1-3s)
- call `$("<li> + data + </li>").appendTo($("#results"))`

The problem is, that the DOM is not refreshed until the loop has terminated. Running the loop for 100 iterations this takes too long, I would like to give a result every time I computed one.

How can I force the DOM to be refreshed?

Comment: http://tobyho.com/2011/11/03/delaying-repeatedly/

Comment: You can also do `.appendto("#results")`, by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in a browser that supports it, [workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Worker) are ideal for this situation.

If not, use `setTimeout` after each computation to break the callstack and allow the browser to use time on rendering.